# How setup subdomains on laravel homestead on macos

Tags: laravel, homestead

I have domain like site.test and 3 subdomains like subdomain1.site.test. It always open site.test.

This is my hosts

```
 192.168.10.10   site.test
 192.168.10.10   subdomain1.site.test
 192.168.10.10   subdomain2.site.test
 192.168.10.10   subdomain3.site.test
```

This is homestead.yaml

```
folders:
- map: ~/Projects/Laravel5/site
  to: /home/vagrant/code/site

sites:
- map: site.test
  to: /home/vagrant/code/site/public
  php: "7.1"
- map: subdomain1.site.test
  to: /home/vagrant/code/site/public
  php: "7.1"
- map: subdomain2.site.test
  to: /home/vagrant/code/site/public
  php: "7.1"
- map: subdomain3.site.test
  to: /home/vagrant/code/site/public
  php: "7.1"
```

Comment: All your subdomains are pointing to the same project, so it’s working as instructed. If you want to display a different page for each subdomain then you either need to handle that at the Laravel level or point your subdomains to other projects in Homestead.